# JBoss Seam tutorials

Tags: web-applications, jboss, frameworks, seam

Let's say that I'm new to JBoss Seam, is there a way to get my skills up to speed?  Are there any good tutorials?

Comment: I also blog lots about seam, check it out at http://shervinasgari.blogspot.com

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You might want to pick up a book called '[Seam In Action](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1933988401)' by Dan Allen. It walks you through all the frameworks that Jboss Seam glues together, not just Jboss Seam itself.

Other than that, you can learn a lot from the examples in Jboss Seam, which you can compile and run almost out of the box, or by using seamgen.

If this is your first time using jsf, hibernate, drools, etc, and you are new to bijection, go for the book.

Answer (score 4):

Seam in Action book is a really good reference about Seam Framework. **Read it carefully** if you want to become a Seam developer. **Take a special look at the following topics**:

**2.3.2** A Q&A session with seam-gen

**2.3.3** Creating a basic project structure

**2.5.3** Exploring the structure of the generated project

**2.6.2** Accelerating development by using an IDE

**Chapter 3** The Seam life cycle

**Chapter 4** Components and contexts

**Chapter 5** The Seam component descriptor

**Chapter 6** Absolute inversion of control

**Chapter 7** The conversation: Seam's unit of work

**Chapter 9** Seam-managed persistence and transaction

Answer (score 2):

See the Seam manual, [Chapter 1. Seam Tutorial](http://docs.jboss.com/seam/latest/reference/en-US/html/tutorial.html).

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your skills in **JSF Life cycle** and **EJB3 (Session Beans and JPA).** Having an idea about those is a must to understand what's the deal with Seam.

You should also read some about **facelets** and **Rich Faces**, since the examples in the tutorial make use of them.

Answer (score 0):

I am also new to java and Seam and am attempting a rather ambitious website!

I agree that the learning curve on this technology is steep if you are not already a java web programmer.

I agree with the comment about breaking it down.  Here are the things that helped me:

Seam in Action -- I can not read a book like this cover-to-cover, but I've read and reread some of the opening chapters and found it helpful.

Start with seam-gen from command line and a basic text editor.  I eventually got my seam app running in eclipse, but it's not as easy as some would have you believe and for me it was just another hurdle to get over.  I am using a simply mysql database as my backend with 3 entities.  The steps are:

```
seam setup  
seam new-project  
seam generate  
seam explode
```

Also, since Seam "knits together" JSF and EJB3 so the next step is to learn each of these.

I am doing a pretty good JSF tutorial right now online.  At http://learn.exadel.com/

If you already know Java, you can probably learn EJB3 fairly easily.

If you don't know Java, start with the intro to Java class at www.javapassion.com.

I'm still experiencing frequent bang head against wall incidents, but it's getting better.

TDR

Answer (score 0):

Seam Manual is enough for startup but you can read Seam In Action and code.google.com/p for sample sourcecodes. One of them is http://sourceforge.net/projects/tekir/. Tekir is written in Seam.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow seam user forum to improve yourself and also i can advise seam in action book to me. And you can understand something through trace seam hotel booking example.

good studies.