# Help me to understand SEAM and Hibernate?

Tags: hibernate, seam, ejb, seam-conversation, seam2

I want to use SEAM Framework with Hibernate but do not want to use EJB. I cannot use EJB.

First question is, can I use EntityManager? or is EntityManager a part of EJB?

How can I get access to use Hibernate in my SEAM component?

Thanks, Philip

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With Seam, you can use either Hibernate or JPA (EntityManager). It works regardless of EJB. You can use plain POJO if you want.

How can I get access to use Hibernate in my SEAM component ?

Here goes Hibernate settings *WEB-INF/components.xml*

**SessionFactory** settings

```
<persistence:hibernate-session-factory name="sessionFactory" cfg-resource-name="app.cfg.xml"/>
```

Where app.cfg.xml is placed in the **root of the classpath**

**Session** settings

```
<persistence:managed-hibernate-session name="session" hibernate-session-factory="#{sessionFactory}" auto-create="true"/>
```

**TransactionManagement** settings

```
<!--It takes care of calling begin and commit in the underlying Transaction API-->
<!--Here a Hibernate Transaction API-->
<tx:hibernate-transaction session="#{session}"/>
```

To inject your Hibernate Session you can use

```
/**
  * Seam lookup Seam enabled components Through its referenced name - session 
  */
private @In Session session;
```

Keep in mind Seam works with any MVC framework although it uses Java Server Faces by default. You can create even your own MVC capabilities if you want. Take a look at [JBoss Seam Tuto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/650647/jboss-seam-tutorials)

Comment: @Phil You can use any persistence technology you want. Not just Hibernate or JPA

Answer (score 0):

The [Seam website](http://www.seamframework.org) is a good place to start. There's a lot of documentation on the framework.

From the FAQ:

> [Do I have to use EJB 3 to use
>   Seam?](http://www.seamframework.org/Documentation/DoIHaveToUseEJB3ToUseSeam)
>
> First, it's important to understand
>   that EJB 3 encompasses session beans,
>   message driven beans, and the Java
>   Persistence API. Seam caters to all
>   three component types, making them
>   easier to use and providing valuable
>   enhancements. But Seam has parallel
>   support for the non-EJB programming
>   model, most notably JavaBeans and
>   native Hibernate. So the choice of
>   what to use is up to you. Seam's
>   greatest strength is that it provides
>   a unified architecture across both the
>   EJB and non-EJB models. That means
>   once you learn how to use one, you
>   automatically know how to use the
>   other.

Answer (score 0):

Another way of getting the Hibernate Session is to use the delegate method on EntityManager:

```
Session session = (Session)entityManager.getDelegate();
```